# Are there good templates and processes for monitoring project progress?

Tags: communication, communication-management

When managing a team of 40-50 team members, are there good processes and templates to monitor project progress?  We do daily standup meetings and weekly email reports, but we're looking for more inspiration.  We still feel that sometimes our team is not always sharing information optimally.

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "we feel sometimes our team is not always sharing information optimally"? What does it mean in terms of impact on your project? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you a technology team? If so, are you following any specific methodologies?

Answer (score 1):

There are many great processes to monitor and control a project.  It begins with the planning process to include estimation.  It includes risk management, quality assurance and control, cost and schedule control using things like EV or critical path management, scope control to include change management and configuration management, verification and validation processes, and communication to name a few.